# React Native How to do OnClick function to bottom tab bar

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

In my project i did "handmade" tab bar without navigation.Firstly i preferred switch case, but now i understood, it cannot be without navigation.I want to change bottom tab navigation. Just i want to pass to other screens when i click bottom tabs but there is no function like "OnClick" in bottom tabs.My handmade router (App.js) menu takes some parameters something like that;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Login from './Login';
import Articles from './Articles';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import Loading from './Loading';
import Register from './Register';
import GotoSearch from './SearchItem';
import GiveDirection from './GiveDirection';
import Navigation from './Navigation';
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.setPage = this.setPage.bind(this);
    this.setCurrentIndex = this.setCurrentIndex.bind(this);
    this.setLastItem = this.setLastItem.bind(this);
    this.state = { currentIndex: null, page: null, LastItem: {latitude : 0 , longitude : 0} }; 
  }
  
  state={
    page:"login"
  }
  setPage(newpage) {
    this.setState({page: newpage});
  }
  setCurrentIndex(id){
    this.setState({currentIndex: id});
  }
  setLastItem(Item){
    this.setState({LastItem:Item})
  }

renderContent = () => {
    switch (this.state.page) {
      case "login":{

    return <Login setPage={this.setPage}/>
  }

  case "articles":{
   
    return <Articles  
    setPage={this.setPage} 
    setLastItem={this.setLastItem} 
    LastItem={this.state.LastItem} 
   />
  }
  case "register":{
    return <Register setPage={this.setPage}/>
  }

  case "gotosearch":{
    return <GotoSearch 
    setPage={this.setPage} 
    currentIndex={this.state.currentIndex} 
    setCurrentIndex={this.setCurrentIndex} />
  }
  case "navigation":{
    return <Navigation 
    setPage={this.setPage}
    setLastItem={this.setLastItem} 
    LastItem={this.state.LastItem} 
    />
  }
  case "givedirection":{
    return <GiveDirection 
    setPage={this.setPage} 
    setLastItem={this.setLastItem} 
    LastItem={this.state.LastItem}
    currentIndex={this.state.currentIndex} 
    setCurrentIndex={this.setCurrentIndex} 
    />
  }
  default:
    return <Loading />
} 
}
```

I want to change from [handmade menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAFSI.png) to [navigation menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxQ8U.png)

And this is the codes of the navigation menu I want to change

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    /*constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    componentDidMount=() => {
        this.props.setPage("articles");
    }
    */
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Text>Home!</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

class SearchScreen extends React.Component {
    
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Text>Search!</Text>              
            </View>
        );
    }
}

class LogoutScreen extends React.Component {
    
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Text>Logout!</Text>              
            </View>
        );
    }
}

class RouteScreen extends React.Component {
    
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Text>Route!</Text>              
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Tabs = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Tab.Navigator>
                <Tab.Screen name="Main" component={HomeScreen}  />
                <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} />
                <Tab.Screen name="Logout" component={LogoutScreen} />
                <Tab.Screen name="Route" component={RouteScreen} />
            </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>     
    )
}
export default Tabs;
```

Comment: Why do you need to track clicks on the tabs? If for navigation, that's actually a responsibility of BottomTabsNavigator.

Comment: when i click the tabs functions start to work.